# javascript function scope and overwriting

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript like this:

```
<script> 

var num = 0;

 if(num==0){
    function lol(){
        alert("lol");
    }
 } else {
    function lol(){
        alert("haha");
    }
 }

</script>
```

Then, later in the page I have:

```
<script>lol();</script>
```

How do I ensure that the first function isn't always overwritten by the second in the else statement?

Thanks

Comment: You have condition here. Therefore this script define just one function the first one or the other one. Ultimately, it depends on condition. In your case will be run alert lol every time you run this script.

Comment: Many great answers, but I'm awarding the 'answered' badge to the person who answered first and stuck to the format I need to comply to :) Thanks again

Comment: Thanks. It's well worth exploring the topics mentioned in fyr's and jAndy's answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
if(num == 0) {
    lol = function() {
        alert("lol");
    };
}
else {
    lol = function() {
         alert("haha");
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No answer provided a proper description of your problem there. So I'll do my very best. The problem you've got there is, that `function declarations` (which is what you got there) are among some other things, interpretated before javascript run-time. This effect is often called `hoisting` and it means that those functions are indeed moved to the top of the current context for the script execution time.

Example, in your snippet, this is what happens:

```
<script> 
    var num = 0;

    function lol(){
        alert("lol");
    }

    function lol(){
        alert("haha");
    }

    if(num==0) {

    } else {

    }
</script>
```

So, an easy solution in this particular instance is, just not to use function declarations but instead a `function expression`. We can force our engine to create a FE in several ways, for instance we can assign it like

```
var num = 0,
    lol;

if( num === 0 ) {
    lol = function() {
        alert('lol');
    };
}
else {
    lol = function() {
        alert('haha');
    };
}
```

A function expression does not get hoisted to the top of the current context, because its not "pre evaluated" by the js engine. So the above code will do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to conditionally define a function, use a function expression to avoid hoisting behavior:

```
var myFunction = someCondition
                   ? function() {
                       alert('foo');
                      }
                   : function() {
                       alert('bar');
                      };

myFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are other answers here which have more code, but I think if you do not know why it is not always overwritten, the best option for you is to understand the source of the problem.

A very exhaustive comparison of different function declarations and an in-depth look is provided here: http://kangax.github.com/nfe/

Its a long article and for sure it will take some time to read, but I think it is better for you and everyone to understand the source of this problem. It will at least save you a lot of time on the long run than just copy paste code.

After reading the article you will know why it is not always overwritten.

Here is the code if you don't feel like reading it:

```
<script> 

var num = 0;
var lol = function(){
        alert("haha");
    };

 if(num==0){
    lol = function(){
        alert("lol");
    };
 }

</script>
```

Comment: I agree with @fyr on the point of getting a better understanding of the language. In general I'd recommended "Javascript: The Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford (ISBN: 978-0596517748). As well as being a good book, it's also pretty short!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> 

var num = 0;

 if(num==0){
    var lol = function(){
        alert("lol");
    }
 } else {
    var lol = function(){
        alert("haha");
    }
 }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you re-structure your code slightly:

```
<script> 

var num = 0;    

function lol(){
    if(num==0){
        alert("lol");
    } else {
        alert("haha");
    }
}
</script>
```